# What's the best way to schedule and execute jruby scripts from within a Rails Three Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I'm working on a rails application that will require a script scheduling and executing component.  I have a variety of scripts that will have to be scheduled and run throughout any given day.  Most of the scripts will complete a task and then insert data into a table within the Rails 3 application.  I have both Ruby and JRuby scripts to schedule and run.  Given these requirements does anyone have any thoughts on a approach to accomplish this. Also, ideally the scripts would run in the background.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS? I have old school moments in some areas so I might just use chron...

Comment: In working in an OS X environment.

Comment: http://www.alastairs-place.net/anacron.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the old-fashioned approach but how about script/runner kicked off by cron?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) to run daily scripts from within a jruby application. My understanding is that it runs periodically using threads, which can be unreliable on regular implementations of Ruby. Since JRuby uses regular Java threads you should be OK.